# Can I detect the uploading/downloading process of Dropbox Core API?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox-api

I'm using Dropbox Core API v1 for iOS and I want to detect the uploading/downloading process.

I understand that `restClient:(DBRestClient *)client uploadedFile:(NSString *)destPath from:(NSString *)srcPath metadata:(DBMetadata *)metadata` method will be called if the upload process is successful and `restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadedFile:(NSString *)destPath contentType:(NSString *)contentType metadata:(DBMetadata *)metadata` for the successful download process.

But what I want is to track the file while its being uploaded/downloaded so I can display it with a UIProgressView or UIActivityIndicatorView.

Help, anyone?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `DBRestClientDelegate`? There are obvious methods for upload and download progress.

Comment: @rmaddy ohh, ok, i see some methods now...
my bad not looking into the `DBRestClientDelegate` first, thanks!